# Matlab assignment error: dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type

Tags: matlab

I would like to create a function that adds a field to a struct with a previously defined value.

I defined:

```
myValue = [1, 3, 5]
```

And I wrote this function:

```
function new_field(myStruct, myName, myValue)
myStruct.(myName) = myValue(:);
end
```

But I get the error:

> "Unable to perform assignment because dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type."

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: How are you calling this function? If you're not passing in a structure as `myStruct` this wont work. You also don't need the `(:)` in `myValue(:);`.

Comment: I'm currently trying to run it from the command window as >> new_field('Struct01', 'discarded', myValue)

Comment: If `Struct01` is already defined then use `new_field(Struct01, 'discarded', myValue)` if not `new_field(struct, 'discarded', myValue)`

Comment: @tor_sten20 by surrounding `Struct01` with quotes, you actually pass a new character vector, not the struct itself. So remove the quotes like user12... suggested.